# How do I list Steam games by release date?

Tags: steam, steamworks-api

I want to get a list of every product on Steam that launched on a given day. Preferably, I'd like to do this without sending an obscene number of API requests and without directly scraping the Steam store's webpage. I only need to do this for games that have already released - it's fine if a solution doesn't work for games with planned future release dates on Steam. It's also fine if this method includes miscellaneous products like DLC that need to be filtered out, as I was planning to write logic for that anyways, but bonus points if there's an easy built-in way to do this.

I looked at some existing solutions for getting Steam games lists, but I couldn't find one that specifically gets games within a certain date range. I also had the idea of using the game's App ID as a way of comparing games chronologically, but early access games would have been assigned an ID long before launch, so this doesn't strike me as a consistent solution either.